# How should I print out data member of string and int in return type of char?

Tags: c++, c++11

I expect to print out "The return value of `getMostFreqLetter(s)`  will be letter 'e', whose frequency is 11."   But the problem that this function only can return char type, I'm stuck on here, and need some help

```
char getMostFreqLetter (string s){

    int maxNum = 0; // the max frequency of occurring of letters
    char maxChar = ' ';   // the max occurring of letters

    /* count the uppercase letters */
    for (char i = 65; i <= 90; i++){ // from A to z based on ascii table value
        int count = 0;  // count the frequency of occurring of letters which compare with maxMun

        for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++){
            if(s[j] == i){
                count ++;
            }

            /*  compare current frequency letters and existing most frequency letters */
            if(count > maxNum){ // display the first alphabet letter if there are multiple same frequency letters occurring
                maxNum = count;
                maxChar = i;
            }
        }
    }

    /* count the lowercase letters */
    for (char i = 97; i <= 122; i++){ // From a to z based on ascii table value
        int count = 0;  // Count the frequency of occurring of letters which compare with maxMun

        for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++){
            if(s[j] == i){
                count ++;
            }

            /* Compare current frequency letters and existing most frequency letters */
            if(count > maxNum){ // display the first alphabet letter if there are multiple same frequency letters occurring
                maxNum = count;
                maxChar = i;
            }
        }
    }

    //cout << "getMostFreqLetter(s) output: letter '" << maxChar <<"', whose frequency is " << maxNum  << "." << endl;

    return maxChar ; 
}
```

BTW, is there easy way to combine the 2 for loops which uppercase and lowercase into one loop?

Comment: BTW, is there easy way to combine the 2 for loops which uppercase and lowercase into one loop?

Comment: So, do you want to return string that prints `maxChar` and frequency of it ?

Comment: Unclear what you ask for! You want return a number, a character? Do you want return the string? Do you want to print and return?

Comment: Do not use magic numbers like 65 and 90. Who knows what those are? Use 'A' and 'Z' instead. It's cleaner and shows the intent. It also works on any character sets as long as the characters are contiguous. The standard doesn't guarantee that it's always ASCII

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll use all alphabet letters instead of numbers then.

Comment: Yea, the return type is "char", but can I return as well as string and int value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest change to your function would be to declare it as:

```
std::pair<char,int> getMostFreqLetter (std::string s){
```

and make the return statement be:

```
return {maxChar, maxNum};
```

Usage would be:

```
const auto freq = getMostFreqLetter(s);
std::cout << "Most frequent letter is " << freq.first
            << " whose frequency is " << freq.second << std::endl;
```

Better would be define a struct `freq_t` with elements `letter` and `frequency` of appropriate types.

To speed things up, I would use an array of size CHAR_MAX, and do something like:

```
   for (const char ch: s)
       freq[(unsigned)ch]++;
```

The cast is because `char` may be signed, if you have a character with the top bit set, you would index of the front of the array.

Then you just have to find the highest element (and the character is the index).

You can extend the array idea to Unicode (which would also avoid the cast) would be to use `std::map<unicode_char,int>` for a suitable choice of `unicode_char`.